# Use android support v7 library classes in my library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I add `android.support.v7.appcompat` library in my project but I am not able to use this library class and methods in it. I have done it again and again but same problem exist any one please help me.

Comment: when i am try to using any of class from android v7 i can't get that in android v7 library

Comment: You can go to your sdk manager and update your support tools to get latest support libaray.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in your app gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

for the design compile this:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Comment: where i can new library Please share link need library for material design